# RxJava- CombineLatest but only fire for one Observable's emission?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java

Let's say I have two infinite Observables that can emit values at any moment. They combine to create a `Observable<ProcessFileEvent>`.

```
Observable<Integer>  selectedFileId= ...
Observable<MouseClick> buttonClick = ...

Observable<ProcessFileEvent> `processFileEvent` = Observable.combineLatest(selectedFileId, buttonClick, (s,b) -> {
    //create ProcessFileEvent here
});
```

The problem is I only want the processFileEvent to emit when `buttonClick` emits something, not `selectedFileId`. It's definitely not the behavior a user expects when a file ID is inputted and it kicks off a `ProcessFileEvent`. How do I combine but only emit when the `buttonClick` emits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.distinctUntilChanged()` on the `MouseClick` object. That way you'll only get events when the `MouseClick` changes.

Create a class that contains both `fileId` and `mouseClick`:

```
static class FileMouseClick {
    final int fileId;
    final MouseClick mouseClick;

    FileMouseClick(int fileId, MouseClick mouseClick) {
        this.fileId = fileId;
        this.mouseClick = mouseClick;
    }
}
```

Then

```
Observable.combineLatest(selectedFileId, buttonClick, 
                         (s,b) -> new FileMouseClick(s,b))
    .distinctUntilChanged(f -> f.mouseClick)
    .map(toProcessFileEvent())
```

Comment: This makes sense. One quick question. Does 'distinct()' rely on 'hashcode()/equals()' for each emitted item or does it suppress dupe sequences?

Comment: a HashSet is used internally. If you have implemented hashCode()/equals() for MouseClick then it better be what you want. If you haven't implemented them then it will be just using object reference equality. Oh, this is overkill I just realized we need to use distinctUntilChanged. I'll update.

Comment: Now that distinctUntilChanged is used, no HashSet is involved but the equals() method is used for the distinct check so you still need hashCode()/equals() behaving as you desire.

Comment: Making this best answer because this solution seems to be the most flexible.

Answer (score 19):

Use [`withLatestFrom`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#withLatestFrom(rx.Observable,%20rx.functions.Func2)):

```
Observable<Integer>  selectedFileId= ...
Observable<MouseClick> buttonClick = ...

Observable<ProcessFileEvent> processFileEvent = buttonClick.withLatestFrom(selectedFieldId, (b,s) -> {
    //create ProcessFileEvent here
});
```

It only emits with when the first `Observable` `buttonClick` emits.

Comment: This should be the accpeted answer as it answers OP's question precisely

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Observable.Join](http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/17_SequencesOfCoincidence.html#Join) to do this. Pay special attention to this paragraph:

> However, what could I do to make sure that these windows did not
>   overlap- so that, once a second value was produced I would no longer
>   see the first value? Well, if we returned the left sequence from the
>   leftDurationSelector, that could do the trick. But wait, when we
>   return the sequence left from the leftDurationSelector, it would try
>   to create another subscription and that may introduce side effects.
>   The quick answer to that is to Publish and RefCount the left sequence.
>   If we do that, the results look more like this.

```
left  |-0-1-2-3-4-5|
right |---A---B---C|
result|---1---3---5
          A   B   C
```

That marble diagram is what you want, where selectedFileId is the left sequence and buttonClick is the right sequence.

Answer (score 0):

this is what worked for me, the missing piece was `startWith()` operators. Once you add it into the observables it will start working working.

Sample

```
         Observable.combineLatest(
                    firstObservable.observeDoors("1").startWith(emptyList<Door>()),
                    secondObservable.observeUnits("2").startWith( emptyList<Door>())
                ) { doors, units ->
                    ArrayList<Door>().apply {
                        addAll(units)
                        addAll(doors)
                    }
                }.map { 
                    //do something 
                }
```

it's because combine needs all the sources to start to emit at least one value and it will initialize the stream and after that just listen to it for changes.